# Product name upsert to a data extension on click and redirection to cloud thank you landing page through AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, upsert

as the title says, I have a number of products in an email in SFMC. On click on any of the products, I'm trying to capture the product clicked on, upsert the name of it to a Data Extension then open / be redirected to a cloud thank you landing page saying something like "Hi FIRSTNAME, thanks for choosing PRODUCTNAME". I want to do this with AMPscript. Can anyone help please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly simple to do. There are 2 options on how to do this.

1. Create a processing page to collect the product and upsert into the DE then redirect to landing page
2. Create a landing page that first collects the product and upserts it to the DE then builds/displays the thank you page through variables and conditions.

My recommendation would be approach 2. This reduces the need for multiple pages, simplifying editing and maintenance - as well as reducing the number of redirects (which can sometimes cause issues if too many)

So for email link you would do something like:

```html
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(1234,"p","apple"))=%%">
```

Where the CloudpagesUrl function would set parameter `p` as the value of 'apple' (or whatever product name you want to pass).

Then on the page, you would put:

```ampscript
%%[
  set @product = RequestParameter("p")
]%%
```

Which would then collect the value of the parameter p that we set in the url in the email.

Then we would upsert it using the **[UpsertData Function](https://ampscript.guide/upsertdata/)**.

From there you just use IF statements and other variables, etc. to create  your page.

Like:

```ampscript
%%[ IF @product == "apple" THEN ]%%
An apple a day keeps the doctor away
%%[ ELSEIF @product == "orange" THEN ]%%
Orange you glad I didn't say apple?
%%[ ELSE ]%%
WATCH OUT FOR DOCTORS!
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Comment: great answer as per usual, thanks so much!